# Python list copy and which to use as class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, copy

I'm confused about the following results, as my understanding is that `[:]` does a shallow copy, and when you change either the old list or the newly copied one, both of them should change? (It was show on one of Coursera courses that I'm following). Also if I want to declare a list as a class variable, with the intent that is the default values and the children classes could override it/modify it if choose to, but the parent one should stay the same, is this the right way to do so ? Many thanks for your help.

```
oldlist=[["a"],"b"]
newlist= oldlist[:]
newlist[0]="2"
oldlist[0].append(["c"])
print(oldlist) #printed out  [['a', ['c']], 'b']
print(newlist) #printed out ['2', 'b']

class Book():
similar_books =['book one','book two']
def __init__ (self, n, l):
    self.name= n
    self.like = l
    self.similar_books = self.similar_books[:]  # is it the correct way to do so?
```

Comment: I think you are getting the desired behavior from the code. you can go ahead in the same way.

Comment: I think you should google : ‘static property in pyhton’ instead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Official Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) a list slice is a shallow copy.  In this case, the shallow copy constructs a new compound object, then inserts a reference to the original contained object.  When the "2" is assigned to the [0] index of newlist, the reference is overwritten and newlist is no longer a compound object.  Had you only appended ["c"] to index [0] of oldlist, you would get the expected shallow copy behavior.

For the second part of your question, objects initialized inside the parent class (but outside the constructor) are static and will not be overridden or modified by children classes.  Out of curiosity, why not just directly assign ['book one','book two'] to self.similar_books within the **init** method?

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, n, l):
        self.name = n
        self.like = l
        self.similar_books = ['book one', 'book two']


class FavouriteBook(Book):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('name', 'like')
        self.similar_books = ['book_3']
```

Comment: Thanks. The idea is that if there's children class, by default the children class will have `similar_books=['book one','book two']` , but the children class could also do something like this to define their own `similar_book` attribute : `class FavouriteBook(Book):
    similar_books = ['book3']`. In this way `FavouriteBook` class has book3 instead of book 1 and 2 as `similar_book`. Is this the way to go?

Comment: Initializing `similar_books=['book one','book two']` prior to the constructor is redundant.  My assumption is that you will invoke the super constructor to assign name and like to the child class,  `super().__init__('name', 'like')`.  Once you invoke the super constructor, the child class inherits similar_books, which can then be overridden with `self.similar_books = ['book_3']`.  Answer updated with example.